# Is RVM supposed to update `.ruby-version` or am I meant to edit it manually?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I upgraded to Ruby 2.0, but when I am in my project directory, entering `rvm use 2.0` followed by `rvm list` shows 2.0 is selected, but my `.ruby-version` file is unchanged. Is this supposed to be the case and I should edit the file manually, or have I missed something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to edit it manually. When you `cd` into the directory with a .ruby-version, rvm will automatically use the version defined in it. So instead of `rvm use 2.0`, just edit your .ruby-version and RVM will automatically switch for you.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you use `rvm use 2.0` its taking affect system wide. But the `.ruby-version` its for project scope and it wont update running this command.

So, you'll need update it manually.